# Dynamics CRM 2013 Workflow C# Extract Field from Linked Entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to get a field from a related CRM Entity in a Dynamics CRM 2013 Workflow. The below code returns the mapped entity but it isn't referencing the matching record in the entity.

How can I update it so it runs the below query against two matched entity Guids?
Do I need to use EntityReference?

```
   QueryExpression FindAddressLots = new QueryExpression(context.PrimaryEntityName);
                    FindAddressLots.LinkEntities.Add
                      (new LinkEntity(context.PrimaryEntityName, "appdetails_data", "applicationdetailsid", "appdetails_dataid", JoinOperator.Inner));
        
             FindAddressLots.LinkEntities[0].Columns.AddColumns("appdetails_dataid", "suburb", "postcode");
    FindAddressLots.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "lotdata";
        
    EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(FindAddressLots);
        
                    foreach (Entity act in ec.Entities)
                    {
        
                      if (act.Attributes.Contains("lotdata.suburb"))
                        {
                          FindAddressLots = act.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("lotdata.suburb").Value.ToString();
                         }
                    }
                }
```

Any suggestions? This would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: few observations/questions.
Are you sure your main Entity schema name is` address_linked_view`. If yes does your `address_linked_view` have field `addressStreet` As the error mentioned in questions talks about  `addressStreet`  I would request for narrowing down issue do not add any linked entity to your queryexpression and try only with main entity and see if it still throws error.

Comment: Hi Ankuser. I removed the LinkEntity and ran with the primary entity. I got the same error with the primary entity. Thanks for the suggestion to check before Linked entity. Do I need to republish my organization web service? I haven't added any new fields (this is an existing field).

Comment: so we can narrow it down your `address_linked_view` entity does not have `addressStreet` field/attribute. You might have to go to your system and check whether such field exist. It can also be that schema name of your field is different.

Also just for rechecking could you add your newly shredded code as well.

Comment: Hi AnkUser. the addressStreet is in the CRM Entity of address_linked_view. I checked in our CRM system and the entity and attribute are there. addressStreet does not exist in the main entity

Comment: What do you mean by not in main entity?  I think you are missing some points here . I would highly recommend you add some screenshot of your address_linked_view entity and also your filed addressStreet field. I still feel field is not in the addrees_linked_view entity.

Comment: The address_linked_view has a field (addressStreet) which I am trying to access from my main entity. Ie - link the Id from the main entity to the address_linked_view to get the correct record.

Comment: Can you try building this query in Advanced find and download the fetchxml to see the schema names?

Comment: I really don't understand the point of hiding the real entity names here. Are they custom entities and your prefix may show the company? then change the prefix to new_ and only that. If you put wrong column names (as it is late bound they should be all lower case) people will concentrate on that and not on your error. Are you sure you are querying an entity and not a view? also you should use AliasedValue when getting values from linked entities (in combination with GetAttributeValue)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestions. Ive updated the code/question now as I have new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clarify one thing first: we don't know the type of field `suburb`, in my code I will assume it's a string but it can be something else.

Query code can be rewritten as the following (link properties, columns and alias are the same):

```
QueryExpression queryAddressLots = new QueryExpression(context.PrimaryEntityName);
LinkEntity linkDetails = queryAddressLots.AddLink("appdetails_data", "applicationdetailsid", "appdetails_dataid", JoinOperator.Inner);
linkDetails.Columns.AddColumns("appdetails_dataid", "suburb", "postcode");
linkDetails.EntityAlias = "lotdata";
EntityCollection collAddressLots = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryAddressLots);
```

According to the code there isn't a logic to retrieve a specific record (but usually there is) otherwise this will return all `Address Lots` joined with the details entity (I also wrote a comment before, nobody cares for the real entity names but they should be exact, when I read a field called `applicationdetailsid` people can assume there is an entity called `applicationdetails` and this entity does not exist)

Second part is how the value is fetched, that can be rewritten as (also here, variable names, something called `act` or `ec` should not be used):

```
foreach (Entity addressLot in collAddressLots.Entities)
{
    AliasedValue aliasSuburb = addressLot.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("lotdata.suburb");
    if (aliasSuburb != null && aliasSuburb.Value != null)
    {
        string suburb = (string)aliasSuburb.Value;
    }
}
```

note that I did a cast to string, because as I wrote before I assumed the field is a string, if the field was a `Whole Number` I would probably do something like `Convert.ToInt32(aliasSuburb.Value)`

Now, the question mentions `it isn't referencing the matching record in the entity`, I assume it refers to the fact (as I wrote before) that no id was provided and all the records were returned. This can be easily solved by adding a condition just after the `QueryExpression` definition, something like:

```
queryAddressLots.Criteria.AddCondition("applicationdetailsid", ConditionOperator.Equal, context.PrimaryEntityId);
```

Of course we can't guarantee if this works, because we don't know the field names, hopefully the author knows. To be honest we can probably just query this `appdetails_data` entity and adding a condition to just match the `applicationdetailsid` (to me it looks like a N:1 relationship and not a 1:N relationship) and querying the `suburb` field without using a `LinkEntity` but I can't be 100% sure.

Hope it helps, and next time, please don't hide the entity and field names, just change the prefix.

Comment: Hi Guido. Thankyou very much for your reply, I have updated my original code again to reflect your suggestions. This definitely links the entity but when I apply the filter I get No entities returned.

Comment: This definitely links the entity but when I apply the filter, No entities returned. -> queryAddressLots.Criteria.AddCondition("applicationdetailsid", ConditionOperator.Equal, context.PrimaryEntityId); The appdetailsid should = company_appdetails_subdivid. The id of my Primary entity will be a different GUID to the GUID which resides in the company_appdetails_subdivId.

Comment: I get the below error with this code 'company_mainapplication' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'company_appdetails_subdivid'.  This is correct, the entity i wish to map to company_mainapplication is the company_applicationdetailsid

Comment: Thanks Guido, your solution worked. I just needed to update to use the correct Ids.